# merge SQL tables into common datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I have 2 SQL tables that I would like to merge to view both simultaneously in a `datagridview`. I can already set this up to view one, via binding it to a dataset, but how can I merge these two based off of a common ID number (for example) that both tables contain?

Current datagridview populate code (the function is fed an empty, new DataTable):

```
public void populateSingleDataGridView(DataTable dt,  DataGridView dg, string SN_DB_Name)
{
     string selectProgramString = "select * from " + SN_DB_Name;
     SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(selectProgramString,connectionString);
     dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     sqlDataAdaptor.Fill(dt);
     dg.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join two tables together:

```
select table1.Field1 as GridColumn1, table2.Field2 as GridColumn2
from table1
    inner join table2
    on table1.CommonId = table2.CommonId
```

If you want to keep your current code as is, then one option is to create a view, e.g.

```
create view GridData
as
    select table1.Field1 as GridColumn1, table2.Field2 as GridColumn2
    from table1
        inner join table2
        on table1.CommonId = table2.CommonId
```

Then you can pass view name into SN_DB_Name.

Note: This option will force you to create views for any queries with joins. IMHO a better option would be to pass an entire sql string.

Good luck

Comment: is that accomplished as a query or in the C# code? I'm using a data adaptor to select all the contents of a single table right now. I just need to figure out how to carry this out, it makes sense.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code you are using?

Comment: added. basically i call this function multiple times to populate say 2 datagridviews.

Answer (score 0):

//Try using alias in your Query
//like this

Select a.ID_number,b.Column1,b.Column2 from YourTable1 a,YourTable2 b
where a.ID_number=b.ID_Number